# How can i keep a task running when the app is closed/killed in react native?

Tags: react-native, socket.io

I want to keep socket io connected even when the app is closed. I have tried the following packages

- react-native-background-task
- react-native-background-timer
- react-native-background-job

Also some other packages. Most of them don't actually run while the app is closed. And some have 15min interval. As i am trying to keep socket io connected they wont work for me. Please suggest something that is tested and working.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: This was the solution for me. But i think there should be a better way to do this.
https://medium.com/reactbrasil/how-to-create-an-unstoppable-service-in-react-native-using-headless-js-93656b6fd5d1